# jQuery sortable not loaded because of Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list (ul li) on my webpage which is converted to a sortable list with jQuery. This all works fine untill i load the list in an Ajax Dialog. Then the list looses its sortable functionality.

Is there any way to re-init the sortable list and keeping all the events i bind to it (like `update`) ??

I tried: `$('#sortable').sortable('refresh');`

But that didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your code or even better load it in a jsFiddle please?

Comment: @Monkieboy That's kinda hard with content loaded through ajax... It's not something easy to put in jsfiddle like an html element that behaves weird or something. This is a common problem that occurs when something is loaded though Ajax. It loses it's javascript functionality. I just haven't seen any solution that worked for me.

Comment: OK, is it possible to get a bit more code even without the AJAX part just so your problem can be replicated?

Comment: @Monkieboy Example: http://jsfiddle.net/un5ft/2/

Comment: Thanks for your example can you let me know if my answer shows understanding of your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Rebind the `sortable()` method again in the callback of your ajax method.

example

```
  $("#someDiv").load("getitems.php",function(){
         $( "#sortableList" ).sortable();
  });
```

Comment: That works, but just the sortable part. I loose all the binds that i attached earlier like the `update` event. That means i have to basically copy the entire `sortable` function i have to the `load` function. I have to keep the code in a general place (site.js), because lists that are not loaded by Ajax make use of it aswell.

Comment: @Vivendi: If you have the events you binded like click,change, bind it using jQuery on method. It will work in dynamically injected DOM (results from AJAX) also.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle it works for me the sortable and injection of content like in your example.

http://jsfiddle.net/un5ft/5/

Comment: The problem is, is that the entire list is loaded in an ajax request. Then it loses its functionality. See jsfiddle.net/un5ft/2

Comment: You can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/un5ft/13/ or do what Shyju has suggested using `on`

Comment: Or vell for that matter too advises use of the on function.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/un5ft/1/), dynamic content don't break sortable functionality, so your problem somewhere else.

**upd:** check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/un5ft/3/). Read more about `.on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: It's more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/un5ft/2/ --- The entire list is loaded in an ajax request. Then it loses its functionality

Comment: Can you fix example? You use `.sortable()` on nonexistent div. You also append divs with same ID.

Comment: That's the whole problem. I have a snippet like that (where i load the `sortable()`) in `general.js` which is always loaded in my html `head` tag. Because some pages which are not loaded by Ajax have a `#sortable` list aswell. Now on a certain page my list gets loaded by Ajax. So you're right. At first the Div ID is non-existent, like in this example. But i'm wondering if there's a way to "rebind" it once the Ajax content is loaded.